# Parse json and create Nest structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, javascript-objects, jsonparser

Sample Input:

```
[
  {
    id: 'p1',
    name: 'Tets1',
    Next: 'p2'
  },
  {
    id: 'p2',
    name: 'Tets2',
    Next: 'p3'
  },
  {
    id: 'p3',
    name: 'Tets3',
    Next: 'p4'
  },
  {
    id: 'p4',
    name: 'Tets4'
  }
]
```

Sample Output :

```
{
  Tets1: {
    {
      id: 'p1',
      name: 'Tets1',
      Next: {
        Tets2: {
          {
            id: 'p2',
            "name": "Tets2",
            "Next": {
              Tets3: {
                id: 'p3',
                "name": "Tets3",
                "Next": {
                  Tets4: {
                    id: 'p4',
                    "name": "Tets4",
                    
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

First object key will be the main key after that if object has new key then it will match with id then match id key will be the key and whole object will e inside it.

I have tried this but it's not properly working. It should work with nested structure

```
 var response = {}
      json.forEach(function (value:any, index) {
                   
                        
                    if(index ==0){
                        response[value.Key] = value
                    }
                        if(value['Next']){
                           let tempData:any = json.find(x => x.id === value['Next'])
                           response[value.Key]['Next'] = {}
                           response[value.Key]['Next'][tempData.Key] = tempData
                        } 
                       
                    }
                   
               });
```

Comment: @ikhvjs I have updated my output . Please check

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, taking advantage of the inherent capability of objects to act as associative arrays is not part of "modern" Javascript.
What a shame, really. It allows to write simple and generic code.
And efficient too: this should run in O(number of nodes) and doesn't require any recursion.

If you don't care about preserving your input, here is a blasphemous, impure version:

```
function MutatingNestStructure (input) {
    let node = [], predecessor = [], root;
    
    for (let item of input) {
        // create a node for each element
        node[item.id] = { [item.name]: item }
        
        // collect predecessors to find root node
        if (item.Next !== undefined) predecessor[item.Next] = item.name;
    }
    for (let item of input) {
        // chain nodes through the "Next" link (clobbering the original object)
        if (item.Next !== undefined) item.Next = node[item.Next];
        
        // Look for a root node. This will fail if the list is circular
        if (predecessor[item.id] === undefined) root = node[item.id];
        // you might also want to check for multiple roots,
        // in case your input defines disjointed lists
    }
    // if the list is circular, you can pick an arbitrary node as root
    // (e.g. node[input[0].id], assuming your input array is not empty)
    // or you might want to leave the result undefined or throw an exception instead
    return root;
}
```

If you want to preserve your input, here is the non-mutating version (only the changes have been commented)

```
function NestStructure (input) {
    let node = [], predecessor = [], root;
    for (let item of input) {
        // shallow copy each item
        node[item.id] = { [item.name]: { ...item } }
        if (item.Next !== undefined) predecessor[item.Next] = item.name;
    }
    for (let item of input) {
        // link nodes instead of items
        if (item.Next !== undefined) node[item.id][item.name].Next = node[item.Next];
        if (predecessor[item.id] === undefined) root = node[item.id];
    }
    return root;
}
```

The complete snippet if you want to play with it:

```js
var input = [
  {
    id: 'p1',
    name: 'Tets1',
    Next: 'p2'
  },
  {
    id: 'p2',
    name: 'Tets2',
    Next: 'p3'
  },
  {
    id: 'p3',
    name: 'Tets3',
    Next: 'p4'
  },
  {
    id: 'p4',
    name: 'Tets4'
  }
];

// variant that mangles its input
function MutatingNestStructure (input) {
  let node = [], predecessor = [], root;
    
  for (let item of input) {
    node[item.id] = { [item.name]: item }
    if (item.Next !== undefined) predecessor[item.Next] = item.name;
  }
  for (let item of input) {
    if (item.Next !== undefined) item.Next = node[item.Next];
    if (predecessor[item.id] === undefined) root = node[item.id];
  }
  return root;
}

// variant that doesn't destroy its input
function NestStructure (input) {
  let node = [], predecessor = [], root;
  for (let item of input) {
    node[item.id] = { [item.name]: { ...item } }
    if (item.Next !== undefined) predecessor[item.Next] = item.name;
  }
  for (let item of input) {
    if (item.Next !== undefined) node[item.id][item.name].Next = node[item.Next];
    if (predecessor[item.id] === undefined) root = node[item.id];
  }
  return root;
}

var result = NestStructure (input)
console.log("PRESERVED INPUT", JSON.stringify(input,null,'   '))
console.log("OUTPUT"         , JSON.stringify(result,null,'   '))

var result = MutatingNestStructure (input)
console.log("CLOBBERED INPUT", JSON.stringify(input,null,'   '))
console.log("OUTPUT"         , JSON.stringify(result,null,'   '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a recursive function:

```js
const json = [
  {
    id: 'p1',
    name: 'Tets1',
    Next: 'p2'
  },
  {
    id: 'p2',
    name: 'Tets2',
    Next: 'p3'
  },
  {
    id: 'p3',
    name: 'Tets3',
    Next: 'p4'
  },
  {
    id: 'p4',
    name: 'Tets4'
  }
];

const processObject = ({ Next, ...rest }) => {
  const result = { ...rest };
  if (Next) {
    const nextObject = json.find((y) => y.id === Next);
    result.Next = {
      [nextObject.name]: processObject(nextObject),
    };
  }
  return result;
};

const response = {
  [json[0].name]: processObject(json[0]),
};

console.log(response);
```

Comment: Is it necessary to define structure in result. Because my json can also have 20 keys

Comment: @user13000875 No, you can use the rest and spread syntax. See my update.

Comment: I am getting one issue. Can you help me on that

Answer (score 0):

You could build an ID to index `Map` to represent a tree and then iterate over the nodes and assign the child nodes.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 'p1', name: 'Tets1', Next: 'p2' },
  { id: 'p2', name: 'Tets2', Next: 'p3' },
  { id: 'p3', name: 'Tets3', Next: 'p4' },
  { id: 'p4', name: 'Tets4' }
];

const buildLinkedList = (data, root) => {
  const tree = data.reduce((acc, { id, name }) =>
    acc.set(name, { id, name }), new Map);

  const idToName = data.reduce((acc, { id, name }) =>
    acc.set(id, name), new Map);

  data.forEach(({ id, name, Next }) => {
    if (Next) {
      const node = tree.get(name);
      if (!node.Next) node.Next = {};
      const found = tree.get(idToName.get(Next));
      node.Next[found.name] = found;
    }
  });

  return { [root]: tree.get(root) };
};

const linkedList = buildLinkedList(data, 'Tets1');

console.log(linkedList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: One change is required my after Next key will be name value not id value